# X makes it look huge or makes it looks huge?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, bare-infinitives

My issue with Kohinoor Black Watch is that the dial shape makes it ***look*** very huge on my skinny 6 and a quarter inch but Pratap's *(a watch)* curvature makes it ***look*** a bit more toned down.

Question - Should that be ***look*** or ***looks***?

I'm 99% sure that I am using look correctly but when I read this sentence, there is this weird itch I feel. My English teacher in school taught me to read something out loud and it'd feel weird if it is wrong. It did work for 11 years.

Answer (score 1):

The correct is "make it look" The form is "make (something) + (bare infinitive)"

> He makes her eat dinner

> She made him pay

> We are making it work

and so on.

Comment: Yes, you'd only use the third person singular _without_ 'make' as in "The Kohinoor Black Watch's dial shape _looks_ huge on my skinny wrist". When  we say that "X makes Y look Z" _makes_ is the main verb and is, therefore, in the third person singular. The verb 'look' (or appear, or seem etc) is not the main verb and the bare infinitive is used.

Answer (score 0):

The correct verb in this case, as @JamesK said, is 'look' (not 'looks'). That's because *make* is the main verb and acts as a 'causative verb' and takes *object* + *[bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)*. You can think of the 'made' as being 'caused X to', for example:

- *He **made** me **do** X*
- **He **made** me **to do** X*

the second one is ungrammatical because the underlying form of *made is*:

- *He **[caused me to]** do X*
- **He **[caused me to] to** do X*

Similarly, we can't use the third person singular verb for *look* in the OP's sentence:

- *He makes it **look** awesome*
- **He makes it **looks** awesome*

- *... the dial shape makes it **look**..*
- **... the dial shape makes it **looks**..*
- *... the dial shape **[causes it to] look***..

---

<sub>A preceding asterisk represents ungrammatical constructions</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have covered why you are correct to use "look" instead of "looks".  "Look" is definitely correct.  However, you mentioned that when you read the sentence outloud, something felt wrong and incorrect.  It looks like you *can* trust that feeling!  You are correct that there is something wrong here, but it's not the "look"... it's the "very huge"!

In English, it is not correct to say very huge. ([Citation](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/huge))  You can say "very big" and "very large", but "very huge" just doesn't work.  Huge, as an adjective, cannot usually<sup>1</sup> take any additional modifiers— you can think of it as having those modifiers built in, as if it said "extremely large" already.

<sup>1 - In casual speech, rude speech, and amongst children, you may hear some other modifiers applied to "huge", such as "stupidly huge", "fucking huge", or a few other possibilities.  Even in these contexts, however, you will not hear "very huge".</sup>